# iOS app becomes unresponsive when html is being rendered in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

If I load request with large content in UIWebView, app becomes unresponsive after it finishes downloading content and starts rendering it. The loaded document also has some Java script content which will be executed on document load.

Also, app crashes if I minimize the app by pressing home button.

How to solve these issues?

Comment: "large content" = scripts, bandwidth, images... what exactly?

Comment: I am calling java script method (stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: API) with large string as an argument.
Also, there is lot of java script execution is going on which is taking time.

Comment: And what devices have you tested on, currently?

Comment: iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4 and iPod touch 5th generation. Same issue in all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

In "Grand Central Dispatch in Practice" section describes your problem and a best-practice solution.

Best regards!

Comment: In that stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: is still called in main thread and not using GCD. Is there any way JS can be executed using GCD.